# AttributeError when webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, attributeerror

Received AttributeError when web-scraping but i am unsure what i a doing wrong? what does AttributeError mean?

```
    response_obj = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_New_York_City').text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response_obj,'lxml')
    Population_Census_Table = soup.find('table', {'class':'wikitable sortable'})
```

preparation of the table

```
    rows = Population_Census_Table.select("tbody > tr")[3:8]

    jurisdiction = []

    for row in rows:
        jurisdiction = {}
        tds = row.select('td')
        jurisdiction["jurisdiction"] = tds[0].text.strip()
        jurisdiction["population_census"] = tds[1].text.strip()
        jurisdiction["%_white"] = float(tds[2].text.strip().replace(",",""))
        jurisdiction["%_black_or_african_amercian"] = float(tds[3].text.strip().replace(",",""))
        jurisdiction["%_Asian"] = float(tds[4].text.strip().replace(",",""))
        jurisdiction["%_other"] = float(tds[5].text.strip().replace(",",""))
        jurisdiction["%_mixed_race"] = float(tds[6].text.strip().replace(",",""))
        jurisdiction["%_hispanic_latino_of_other_race"] = float(tds[7].text.strip().replace(",",""))
        jurisdiction["%_catholic"] = float(tds[7].text.strip().replace(",",""))
        jurisdiction["%_jewish"] = float(tds[8].text.strip().replace(",",""))
    
        jurisdiction.append(jurisdiction)

` `print(jurisdiction)
```

> AttributeError
>
> ```
>    ---> 18     jurisdiction.append(jurisdiction)
>    AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with `jurisdiction` as a list and immediately make it as a dict. You then treat as a dict until the error line where you try to treat it again as a list. I think you need another name for the list at the start. Possibly you meant *jurisdictions* (plural) as list. However, IMO there are two other areas that also definitely need fixing:

1. *find* returns a single table. The labels/keys in your dict indicate you want to a later table (not the first match)
2. Your indexing is incorrect for the target table

You want something like:

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response_obj = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_New_York_City').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response_obj,'lxml')
Population_Census_Table = soup.select_one('.wikitable:nth-of-type(5)') #use css selector to target correct table.
jurisdictions = []
rows = Population_Census_Table.select("tbody > tr")[3:8]
for row in rows:
    jurisdiction = {}
    tds = row.select('td')
    jurisdiction["jurisdiction"] = tds[0].text.strip()
    jurisdiction["population_census"] = tds[1].text.strip()
    jurisdiction["%_white"] = float(tds[2].text.strip().replace(",",""))
    jurisdiction["%_black_or_african_amercian"] = float(tds[3].text.strip().replace(",",""))
    jurisdiction["%_Asian"] = float(tds[4].text.strip().replace(",",""))
    jurisdiction["%_other"] = float(tds[5].text.strip().replace(",",""))
    jurisdiction["%_mixed_race"] = float(tds[6].text.strip().replace(",",""))
    jurisdiction["%_hispanic_latino_of_other_race"] = float(tds[7].text.strip().replace(",",""))
    jurisdiction["%_catholic"] = float(tds[10].text.strip().replace(",",""))
    jurisdiction["%_jewish"] = float(tds[12].text.strip().replace(",",""))
    jurisdictions.append(jurisdiction)
```